# Whether to use a preposition in this sentence construction

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Context:

> It is animals and plants which lived in or near water whose remains
> are most likely to be preserved. ... The remains of plants and animals
> that lived on land are much more rarely preserved, **for there is
> seldom anything to cover them over**. ...They decompose and get
> quickly destroyed by weather, or they are eaten by some other
> creature.
>
> By Errol Ivor White (1901-1985),  The Past Life of the Earth, Discovery,
> 1961

My rewrite:

> **for there is seldom anything to cover them over with**.

Which is more common? Are both correct?

Comment: What's the context? Have you looked up sentences with "cover", visit Lexico to find examples. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cover BTW to put "over" something or "cover" something have similar meanings. *Put a blanket over him* VS *Cover him with a blanket*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for pointing out. I just provided the context. Do you want to answer?

Comment: The original is fine. There is no need to add "with". The substance that covers and preserves the dead bodies of animals will be silt, mud, sand, ash etc. If I physically use a type of material to cover something over then I might add "with", e.g. *I **covered** (over) the bird's eggs **with** soft wool, feathers, and straw*. Which means the eggs were completely "hidden" from sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep "with".

Here is what the *phrasal verb* **cover over** means:

> Put something on top of something else so that it is completely hidden. ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cover-over))
> *The female lays a single egg and covers it over.*

> Cover something completely so that it cannot be seen ([Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cover-over?q=cover%20over))
> *The Roman remains are now covered over by office buildings.*

> Put one thing over another, in order to protect or hide it ([Longman](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cover_1?q=cover%20over#cover_1__1))
> *The floor was covered with plastic sheeting.*

So basically you can either just use:
*cover something over*
Or if you want to mention what was used to cover something over:
*cover something over with/by something/nothing*

To clarify, "over" doesn't work as a preposition here. It's a part of the phrasal verb "cover over".

Putting it another way:

You **cover something** *with/by something*. (This doesn't necessarily tell us if it was covered completely or not.)
You **cover something over** *with/by something*. (This emphasizes that it was covered completely.)

---

EDIT:

**With the context @joy2020 has now provided, I think the sentence makes much more sense without the preposition "with".**

Comment: To be fair, when PPH answered this, I didn't provide context, but just presented a standalone sentence: **There is nothing to cover the bodies over (with)**. I thought this wouldn't interfere with the question, which is whether to use a preposition in this sentence construction.